How to Create Custom Armor with a Default Enchantment in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?
I'm working on a custom add-on for Minecraft Bedrock Edition and trying to create a piece of custom armor that comes with a default enchantment (e.g., a chestplate with Thorns right out of the box).
I’ve managed to create the custom armor piece itself, but I’m stuck on how to apply the enchantment to it by default. Ideally, I want the enchantment to show up when the player equips the item, but I’m not sure how to configure this in the behavior_pack or resource_pack files.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Defined the custom armor in the items.json.
Used a component group to try applying the enchantment, but no luck.
Looked into minecraft:enchantable, but it seems that only defines what can be enchanted, not pre-applied enchantments.
Does anyone have experience with this? Is it even possible to pre-enchant armor in Bedrock, or will I need to use some kind of command or script workaround?

As far as I know, it isn't possible. In my own addons, I've made custom tools "pre-enchanted" with Silk Touch, but it's really a workaround made by setting the "minecraft:glint" property to true in the tool's item.json file, and adding event listeners for entityHitBlock and playerInteractWithBlock within the main.js script file. The enchantment actually gets applied the first time the tool is used (right or left click on a block) and so for all blocks that do not break instantly, even the first use will have the enchantment, but it isn't technically 'default.'

I wish there were something like a playerTakeItemFromCraftingGrid event listener, but there isn't (so far). Until there is, I'd recommend using the entityHitEntity event listener to detect when the player takes melee damage, then check whether the player is wearing your custom armor and, if so, enchant it. For the first instance of the player being attacked, you can manually call the .applyDamage method on event.damagingEntity with EntityDamageCause object property cause set to "thorns", so that even the first use counts.

Here's an example of a custom armor "enchantment" that deals knockback to any entity that attacks a player wearing it: https://imgur.com/a/5COQWY2.
